# Cutting roll media from epson p900

Tags: printing, paper, ink-jet

I have an Epson Surecolor P900 (SC-P900) with the roll media adapter. I am able to use it as expected, everything is coming out satisfactory, but I am having trouble cutting the paper in a straight line as it comes out. I have tried feeding it through a guillotine and roller cutter but it is extremely hard to fit the paper through it while still attached to the printer on the other end without scratching it. Using scissors works but is extremely difficult to cut straight. I have also tried using an exacto knife but similar issue with either risking scratching the print by using a ruler to guide the cut or making a crooked line.

What is recommended in this case? The manual does not offer a lot of guidance here and I haven't found a good reference for people using roll media in this printer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After printing you can feed the paper to a cutting position. The manual says:

**Cutting and Removing the Roll Paper**
After printing on the roll paper, follow the steps below to remove the roll paper.

1. Select Cut/Eject on the printer's control panel.
2. Select Cut and Eject.The roll paper is moved to the cutting position.
3. Cut the ejected paper using scissors.
4. Select Done.

This will of course waste a bit of paper, but is the usual way to work with paper rolls. First roughly cut, then trim to desired borders on a cutting mat.

https://www.manua.ls/epson/surecolor-sc-p900/manual?p=35

Note: If the margin for cutting is too small for you, I guess the way would be to eject the paper twice. A bit more waste, but it would give you more margin for error while cutting. And please not that it is rather usual to first cut roughly and then trim to the desired final margin afterwards using a metal ruler and exacto knife on a cutting mat.

Comment: ↑ …and let it dry thoroughly before cutting. It might feel touch-dry, but it will still be quite soft initially.

Comment: There are several issues i'm having with this process:
* it is very difficult for me to get a straight line just using scissors (shaky hands :/)
* it is difficult to not scratch or bend the print (for example a completed 17x22 print hanging off the edge while still attached to the printer) while performing the cut/eject process.
* it is difficult to measure the "top" (first printed) and "bottom" (last part) margins precisely following an scissor cut by hand on both sides. That is, it is difficult to measure the desired border when there is no actual paper end edge to measure from.

Comment: @thatfunkymunki measure from the printed edge.

Comment: @thatfunkymunki If you eject twice you get more space and margin to do the initial cut. Trim the rough cut afterwards when you can lay it flat to avoid damaging the print.